# Implement a function called num_charging_stops that calculates the minimum number of charging stops needed to reach the destination

Tags: python

```
def num_charging_stops(legs: List[int], capacity: int) -> int:
```

Calculates the number of necessary charging stops to reach the destination.

Each "leg" of your journey represents the amount of energy required to drive
that leg of the trip. For example, if a leg has a value of 5 and your
battery's energy level before driving the leg is 12, then driving that leg
will drop the battery's energy level to 7 (12-5). After driving each leg, you
have the choice of whether to charge or not. If you decide to charge, your
battery's energy level get's returned to "capacity". If you decide not to
charge, your battery's energy level is unchanged. The goal is to calculate
the minimum number of charging stops needed to reach the destination without
ever letting your battery's level fall below 0. If it isn't possible to reach
the destination with the given inputs, -1 should be returned.

Assume that your battery is charged to full capacity to start.

```
  Examples:
    num_charging_stops([25], 30) -> 0
    num_charging_stops([25, 25], 30) -> 1
    num_charging_stops([50], 30) -> -1
    num_charging_stops([15, 15, 30]) -> 1
    num_charging_stops([15, 30, 15]) -> 2
```

Tried solution:

```
from typing import List

def num_charging_stops(legs: List[int], capacity: int) -> int:
    current_energy = capacity
    charging_stops = 0

    for leg in legs:
        current_energy -= leg

        if current_energy < 0:
            current_energy = capacity
            charging_stops += 1

    if current_energy < 0:
        return -1

    return charging_stops
```

Question:

1. I'm not getting the required output. Getting 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 as output.
2. Is there a more optimal solution?

Comment: the last 2 examples make no sense. they only provide `legs` and not `capacity`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is that you're allowing your charge to go below 0 and then you try to charge which isn't allowed. This should work:

```
def num_charging_stops(legs, capacity):
    times_charged = 0
    current_charge = capacity
    for leg in legs:
        if leg > capacity:
            return -1
        if leg > current_charge:
            times_charged += 1
            current_charge = capacity
        current_charge -= leg
    return times_charged

print(num_charging_stops([25], 30))
print(num_charging_stops([25, 25], 30))
print(num_charging_stops([50], 30))
print(num_charging_stops([15, 15, 30], 30))
print(num_charging_stops([15, 30, 15], 30))
```

Answer (score -1):

Trying out various scenarios and shuffling the test and capacity replenishment, the following refactored code seemed to address the issue of proper point of replenishment and testing.

```
def num_charging_stops(legs, capacity):
    current_energy = capacity
    charging_stops = 0

    for leg in legs:

        if current_energy <= leg:       # Checking current energy versus leg amount seemed to work
            current_energy = capacity   # If fully charged, no additional energy will be added
            charging_stops += 1

        current_energy -= leg           # After leg check and possible replenishment, then decrement

    if current_energy < 0:
        return -1

    print("Remaining capacity", current_energy)

    return charging_stops

print("Stops", num_charging_stops([25], 30))
print("Stops", num_charging_stops([25, 25], 30))
print("Stops", num_charging_stops([50], 30))
print("Stops", num_charging_stops([15, 15, 30], 30))
print("Stops", num_charging_stops([15, 30, 15], 30))
```

The key point was testing for possible replenishment for a leg prior to replenishment.

Using your test scenarios, following was the output at the terminal.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Charging$ python3 Charging.py 
Remaining capacity 5
Stops 0
Remaining capacity 5
Stops 1
Stops -1
Remaining capacity 0
Stops 1
Remaining capacity 15
```

That appears to match up with the desired output from the test scenarios.  Give that some testing.

Comment: your solution is wrong. `num_charging_stops([50, 15, 15], 30)` returns 3 instead of -1 because you didn't put the energy check inside the loop

Comment: You are correct.  Need to go have another coffee.  Good catch.  I will gladly take the hit.